# Toggle edit and display of the fields in a form

Tags: angularjs, forms, input, directive

Above all, I have the plnkr at [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWJtLQCpkV195DTdbPFf?p=preview).

I am trying to create a series of directive that support in-place toggle of text display and edit within a form. As I understand, there is a similar module like `xeditable` available, but we need to do something different down the road. So I started with an experiment to start with something similar.

First, I create a directive that allows toggling edit/display by setting an attribute `editEnabled` on the directive called `editableForm`. The following code does not do anything special other than a line of log message.

```
function editableForm ($log) {

        var directive = {
            link: link,
            require: ['form'],
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                editEnabled: "&editEnabled"
            }
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs, controller) {


             //$log.info('editEnabled: ' + scope.editEnabled());
            $log.info('editEnabled: ' + attrs.editEnabled); //this also works


        }
    } //editableForm
```

Then I wrote the following directive to override the `input` tag in html:

```
 //input directive
    function input($log) {

        var directive = {
            link: link,
            priority: -1000,
            require: ['^?editableForm', '?ngModel'],
            restrict: 'E'
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$render = function() {
                        if (!ngModel.$viewValue || !ngModel.$viewValue) {
                            return;
                        }
                        element.text(ngModel.$viewValue);
                    };
                $log.info('hello from input');
                $log.info('input ngModel: ' + attrs.ngModel);
                // element.val('Hello');

            scope.$apply(function() {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue('hello');
                            ngModel.$render();
                        });


        }
    } //input
```

I was trying to show the `ngModel` value of the input as text in the `input` directive, however, it doesn't seem to do anything in my testing. Could someone spot where I am doing wrong? I wish to replace each input fields with text/html (e.g. `<span>JohnDoe</span>` for Username).

My first attempt on input is a proof of concept. If it works, I will keep working on other tags like `button`, `select`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Long shot here... Your requiring both `editableForm` and `ngModel` in your `input` directive. So the fourth parameter of your link function should be an array of controllers in the respective order of the `require` array, not the `ngModel` controller as you are expecting.

I didnt go any further in examining your code, but check it out.